# WebPart in Sharepoint freezes after clicking a linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a user control inside a webpart inside sharepoint that I add some linkbuttons dynamically during runtime. each one when clicked is supposed to download a certain file from the database. however when one of those linkbuttons is clicked, this file is downloaded for once and then i can't click any other buttons or links or even the same one again on this user control and webpart. but i can still click other things outside the user control and webpart. do u have any idea? please tell me which part of the code i can add here if you need to check something. thank you :)

```
    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

public class SearchResult : IComparable
{
    private string __nID;
    private string __sQuestion;
    private string __sAnswer;
    private string __nCategoryID;
    private string __nPermission;
    private string __nLastEdit;
    private int __nOccurrence;

    public SearchResult()
    {
        __nOccurrence = 0;
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return __nID; }
        set { __nID = value; }
    }
    public string Quest
    {
        get { return __sQuestion; }
        set { __sQuestion = value; }
    }
    public string Answer
    {
        get { return __sAnswer; }
        set { __sAnswer = value; }
    }
    public string CategoryID
    {
        get { return __nCategoryID; }
        set { __nCategoryID = value; }
    }
    public string Permission
    {
        get { return __nPermission; }
        set { __nPermission = value; }
    }
    public string LastEdit
    {
        get { return __nLastEdit; }
        set { __nLastEdit = value; }
    }
    public int Occurrence
    {
        get { return __nOccurrence; }
        set { __nOccurrence = value; }
    }

    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(SearchResult res)
    {
        if (this.Occurrence > res.Occurrence)
            return -1;
        if (this.Occurrence < res.Occurrence)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        SearchResult res = (SearchResult)obj;
        if (this.Occurrence > res.Occurrence)
            return -1;
        if (this.Occurrence < res.Occurrence)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }

    #endregion
}

[System.ComponentModel.Description("Questions")]
public partial class SampleProvider : System.Web.UI.UserControl, SmartPart.IConnectionProviderControl
{
    const string FAQConnectionString = "";
    private int FileID = 1;
    private string CaregoryID = "1";

    TextBox tbQuestion;
    TextBox tbAnswer;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["CategoryID"] = "0";
            LoadTree();
        }

        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string username = context.User.Identity.Name;

        LoadQuestions();
    }

    void LoadQuestions()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Questions";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Clear();

        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/><br/><br/>"));
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (ViewState["CategoryID"].ToString() != dr[3].ToString())
                continue;

            Label question = new Label();
            question.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            question.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            question.Font.Bold = true;
            question.Font.Size = 11;
            question.Width = 500;

            Label answer = new Label();
            answer.Text = dr[2].ToString();
            answer.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            answer.Font.Size = 11;
            answer.Width = 500;

            LinkButton lnkbtnEdit = new LinkButton();
            lnkbtnEdit.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtnEdit_Click);

            lnkbtnEdit.CommandArgument = dr[0].ToString();
            lnkbtnEdit.CommandName = "edit";

            lnkbtnEdit.Text = "Edit";
            lnkbtnEdit.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            lnkbtnEdit.Font.Size = 11;
            lnkbtnEdit.Width = 50;

            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(question);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(answer);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            /////////////////////////// dr[2] for the QuestionID column at the question table
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE QuestionID = " + dr[0].ToString();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader drr;

            conn.Open();
            drr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (drr.Read())
            {
                LinkButton lnkbtnDownloadFile = new LinkButton();

                //name of the file ---> drr[2]
                lnkbtnDownloadFile.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtnDownloadFile_Click);
                lnkbtnDownloadFile.Text = drr[2].ToString();
                lnkbtnDownloadFile.CommandArgument = drr[2].ToString();


                PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(lnkbtnDownloadFile);
                PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            }

            ShowLabels(dr[0].ToString());




            conn.Close();
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(lnkbtnEdit);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p/>"));

        }
        con.Close();

    }

    void EditQuestion(string ID)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'");
        com.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();

        string quest="";
        string answer = "";
        string categoryID = "";
        string lastEdit = "";

        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            quest = dr[1].ToString();
            answer = dr[2].ToString();
            categoryID = dr[3].ToString();
            lastEdit = dr[5].ToString();
        }


        tbQuestion = new TextBox();
        tbAnswer = new TextBox();

        tbQuestion.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        tbAnswer.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;

        tbQuestion.Width = 360;
        tbAnswer.Width = 360;

        tbQuestion.Text = quest;
        tbAnswer.Text = answer;

        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Clear();
        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(tbQuestion);
        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(tbAnswer);


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        /////////////////////////// dr[2] for the QuestionID column at the question table
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE QuestionID = " + ID;
        SqlDataReader drr;

        conn.Open();
        drr = comm.ExecuteReader();

        PlaceHolder PlaceHolderFiles = new PlaceHolder();
        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(PlaceHolderFiles);

        // for showing links to the files
        while (drr.Read())
        {
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();

            //name of the file ---> drr[2]
       //     lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);
            lb.Text = drr[2].ToString();

            PlaceHolderFiles.Controls.Add(lb);


            LinkButton lnkbtnDelete = new LinkButton();
            //      lnkbtnDelete.Click+= new EventHandler(delete_Click);
            lnkbtnDelete.CommandArgument = lb.Text;
            lnkbtnDelete.Text = "Delete";
            lnkbtnDelete.Width = 60;
            lnkbtnDelete.Height = 25;
            PlaceHolderFiles.Controls.Add(lnkbtnDelete);

            PlaceHolderFiles.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }

        LinkButton lnkbtnSave = new LinkButton();
        lnkbtnSave.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtnSave_Click);
        lnkbtnSave.Text = "Save";
        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(lnkbtnSave);

        conn.Close();   
    }

    void lnkbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is LinkButton && (sender as LinkButton).CommandName == "save")
            SaveQuestion((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    }

    private  void UpdateQuestionByID(int questionID, string question, string answer, string lastEdited)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(FAQConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            const string QUERY =
                @"UPDATE Questions " +
                @"SET Question = @Question, Answer = @Answer, LastEdit = @LastEdited " +
                @"WHERE ID = @QuestionID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QUERY, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", question);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", answer);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastEdited", lastEdited);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionID", questionID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    void SaveQuestion(string ID)
    {
        UpdateQuestionByID(int.Parse(ID), tbQuestion.Text, tbAnswer.Text, "a");
    }

    void lnkbtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (sender is LinkButton && (sender as LinkButton).CommandName=="edit") 
        //    EditQuestion((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        string id = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("http://kermit:91/BIMS/Shared%20Documents/EditQuestion.aspx?k="+id);
        ViewState["EditID"] = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    }

    void lnkbtnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is LinkButton)
            DownloadFile((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    }

    private void DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE FileName = @ID";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fileName;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader sqlRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sqlRead.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlRead.Read())
            {
                byte[] fileData = (byte[])sqlRead[3];

                Response.Clear();
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sqlRead[2]);
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
                //Response.Flush();
                //Response.End();
                Response.Clear();
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        sqlRead.Close();

    }

    protected void lnkbtnAddQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void LoadTree()
    {
        tvCategory.Nodes.Clear();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuestionCategory WHERE ParentCategoryID = -1";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
            tn.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            tn.Value = dr[0].ToString();

            tvCategory.Nodes.Add(tn);
            AddChildren(tn);
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void AddChildren(TreeNode tn)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuestionCategory WHERE ParentCategoryID = " + tn.Value;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            TreeNode ctn = new TreeNode();
            ctn.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            ctn.Value = dr[0].ToString();

            tn.ChildNodes.Add(ctn);
            AddChildren(ctn);
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    protected void tvCategory_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["CategoryID"] = tvCategory.SelectedValue;
      //  CaregoryID = tvCategory.SelectedValue;

        LoadQuestions();
        tvCategory.SelectedNode.Selected = false;
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable QuestionsTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection(FAQConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Questions", oCn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adp.Fill(QuestionsTable);
        }

        List<String> wordsSearched = new List<string>();
        List<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();

        string[] words = txtbxSearch.Text.ToLower().Split();

        //filtering the unnecessary words to prevent searching for
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            if (s == "to" || s == "the" || s == "is" || s == "are" || s == "in" || s == "of" || s == "on" || s == "with" || s == "are" || s == "it" || s == "this")
                continue;
            wordsSearched.Add(s);
        }

        //adding the search result and determine the frequency of occurrence
        for (int i = 0; i < QuestionsTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            foreach (string w in wordsSearched)
                if (QuestionsTable.Rows[i][1].ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(w) > -1 || QuestionsTable.Rows[i][2].ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(w) > -1)
                {
                    SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
                    result.ID = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    result.Quest = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    result.Answer = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                    result.CategoryID = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                    result.Permission = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][4].ToString();
                    result.LastEdit = QuestionsTable.Rows[i][5].ToString();
                    result.Occurrence++;

                    bool isFound = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < searchResults.Count; j++)
                        if (searchResults[j].ID == result.ID)
                        {
                            searchResults[j].Occurrence++;
                            isFound = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    if (!isFound)
                        searchResults.Add(result);
                }

        SearchInTags(wordsSearched, searchResults);
        searchResults.Sort();
        //Session["SearchResults"] = searchResults;
        //Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx");


        LoadSearchResults(searchResults, wordsSearched);
    }

    void SearchInTags(List<string> words, List<SearchResult> searchResults)
    {
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(FAQConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Questions INNER JOIN QuestionKeyword ON Questions.ID=QuestionKeyword.QuestionID INNER JOIN Keywords  ON QuestionKeyword.KeywordID=Keywords.ID WHERE Keywords.Keyword LIKE '%" + s + "%'", con);
                SqlDataReader dr;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
                    result.ID = dr[0].ToString();
                    result.Quest = dr[1].ToString();
                    result.Answer = dr[2].ToString();
                    result.CategoryID = dr[3].ToString();
                    result.Permission = dr[4].ToString();
                    result.LastEdit = dr[5].ToString();
                    result.Occurrence++;

                    bool isFound = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < searchResults.Count; j++)
                        if (searchResults[j].ID == result.ID)
                        {
                            searchResults[j].Occurrence++;
                            isFound = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    if (!isFound)
                        searchResults.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    string[] ColorWords(string[] words, string color, List<string> selected)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<selected.Count; j++)
                if(words[i].ToLower()==selected[j].ToLower())
                {
                    words[i] = "<span style='color: red;'>" + words[i] + "</span>";
                    break;
                }

        return words;

    }


    string ColorText(string text, List<string> selected)
    {
        int searchFrom = 0;
        foreach (string s in selected)
        {
            int startIndex = text.ToLower().IndexOf(s, searchFrom);
            if (startIndex < 0)
                continue;

            int length = s.Length;
            text = text.Insert(startIndex, "<span style='color: red;'>");
            text = text.Insert(startIndex + length + 26, "</span>");
        }

        return text;
    }

    void LoadSearchResults(List<SearchResult> searchResults, List<string> selected)
    {

        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Clear();

        foreach (SearchResult res in searchResults)
        {
            Label question = new Label();
            question.Text = ColorText(res.Quest, selected);
            question.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            question.Font.Bold = true;
            question.Font.Size = 11;
            question.Width = 500;

            Label answer = new Label();
            answer.Text = ColorText(res.Answer, selected);
            answer.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            answer.Font.Size = 11;
            answer.Width = 500;

            HyperLink edit = new HyperLink();

            string url = "http://kermit:91/BIMS/Shared%20Documents/EditQuestion.aspx?k=";
            url += res.ID;


            edit.NavigateUrl = url;
            edit.Text = "Edit";
            edit.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            edit.Font.Size = 11;
            edit.Width = 50;



            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(question);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(answer);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = FAQConnectionString;

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            /////////////////////////// dr[2] for the QuestionID column at the question table
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE QuestionID = " + res.ID;
            SqlDataReader drr;

            conn.Open();
            drr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (drr.Read())
            {
                LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();


                //name of the file ---> drr[2]
                //            lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);
                lb.Text = drr[2].ToString();

                PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(lb);
                PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            }

            ShowLabels(res.ID);

            conn.Close();
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(edit);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p/>"));

        }
    }

    void ShowLabels(string questionID)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(FAQConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuestionKeyword INNER JOIN Keywords ON QuestionKeyword.KeyWordID=Keywords.ID  WHERE QuestionID = " + questionID;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Label lblKeyword = new Label();
            lblKeyword.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblKeyword.Text = dr[4].ToString();
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(lblKeyword);
            PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" \t "));
        }


        con.Close();

        PlaceHolderQuestions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p/>"));
    }


    #region IConnectionProviderControl Members

    public object GetProviderData()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string ProviderMenuLabel
    {
        get { return "Sends text data to"; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**the weird thing that it works well when i put the same code in an asp.net page!!**

Comment: Wow! That is a huge piece of code!

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237921. If you aren't getting the answers you want Ahmad, edit your question with what you've been trying and it will bump to the top of the Active list for the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmad,

Check out the following link on the MSDN forums, as I believe the situation is similar (if not identical) to what you're describing:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/107b2c17-07fe-4a15-ad81-dcb31e1e9c84/

A couple of different approaches/solutions are discusssed.

I hope this helps!